# How to use xml object repository for android parallel test execution

Tags: xml, object, parallel-processing, repository, appium

I am trying for Parallel Execution of My Selenium Test code on 2 Android devices . 
Object Repository - XML 
Device - Android Real device
Appium version - 1.13
Java-client - 6.0.0

When running test in parallel mode , App launching on both device, after that when i am trying to access element , on 1st device able to access and test proceed , but in second device appium not able to find the elements. and test fail in 2nd device by saying not able to locate element .

if i run test as a single test , it pass on both device , but fail in parallel mode.

is there any issue of accessing element from xml in parallel mode .

please suggest how to use object repository in parallel mode

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you haven't applied [ThreadLocal Storage pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) to your [AndroidDriver](https://appium.github.io/java-client/io/appium/java_client/android/AndroidDriver.html) instances. You should be storing AndroidDriver under [ThreadLocal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html) something like:

```
ThreadLocal<AndroidDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();
// initialize AndroidDriver normally
driver.set(new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://url-of-your-appium-server"),capabilities));
```

and whenever you need to refer the AndroidDriver - do it like:

```
driver.get().findElements....
```

More information:

- [Appium Parallel Execution using TestNG](https://www.toolsqa.com/mobile-automation/appium/appium-parallel-execution-using-testng/)
- [Parallel Tests - Best Practices](https://docs.experitest.com/display/TE/Parallel+Tests+-+Best+Practices)
- [Parallel Android Tests](http://appium.io/docs/en/advanced-concepts/parallel-tests/)